# Handle response from post request to Json

Tags: go

I'm using the following code to get a response from a server after a post request:

```
type ResponseFromPost struct {
    N_expediente string
    Enviar string
}

func main(){

    ......

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    var re ResponseFromPost
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &re)
    fmt.Println(re.Enviar);
}
```

With this I get:

```
    error: &{%!e(string=array) %!e(*reflect.rtype=&{32 2509985895 0 8 8 25 0x608170
[0x7703c0 <nil>] 0x730b80 0x69acb0 0x6116c0 0x7732c0})}
```

The value sent by the server is:

```
[{"n_expediente":"9","enviar":"2"}]
```

How can I use the json variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json is an array of those objects having the strings `n_expediente` and `enviar` on each instance. In the Go you'll need an array of your type;

```
re := []ResponseFromPost{} 
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`[{"n_expediente":"9","enviar":"2"}]`), &re)
fmt.Println(re[0].Enviar);
```

Here's an example to show what your model needs to be https://play.golang.org/p/d64Sict4AG

You'll probably want to make some other changes to your code based on that. Like a loop bound by the length of the slice ( `for i := range re { print i }` ) after the unmarshal and a different name for the type.